# Refocus To Terminal after Matlab Plt

Tags: python, linux, matlab, numpy, matplotlib

Currently trying to pull up figures that go with a response, whenever I open the figure (plt.draw) it pans focus to the picture and the user has to click back to the terminal each time the picture is called. I am trying to get it where the figure is a background object (so it will open but it won't shift focus) or possibly manually shift the Foreground Window to the terminal or the file name the code is running on. Also trying to make it linux and windows friendly so can't be windows specific commands, but anything helps. My code is provided below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

def ShowImageCommon(wintitle = "", imgpath = "", imgtitle = "", imgshowdelay = 5):
    ImageAddress = imgpath
    ImageItself = Image.open(ImageAddress)
    ImageNumpyFormat = np.asarray(ImageItself)

    plt.title(imgtitle)
    figure = plt.gcf()
    # figure.set_visible(not figure.get_visible())
    figure.canvas.set_window_title(wintitle)
    axis = plt.gca()
    x_axis = axis.axes.get_xaxis()
    x_axis.set_visible(False)
    y_axis = axis.axes.get_yaxis()
    y_axis.set_visible(False)
    plt.show()
    
    return ImageNumpyFormat

def ShowImageInteractive(wintitle = "", imgpath = "", imgtitle = "", imgpause = 0):
    while True:
        try:
            ImageNumpyFormat = ShowImageCommon(wintitle, imgpath, imgtitle)
            plt.imshow(ImageNumpyFormat)
            plt.draw()
            plt.pause(0.1) # Window closes after specified delay in sec
            return plt
        except:
            imgpath = input(f'Could not open image path {imgpath}, please type path here >> ')

def main():
    imgpause = 0.1
    wintitle = 'UIB Functional Test'
    imgpath = '{path to file}/Keypad Press Sequence.png'
    imgtitle = 'Keypad Press Sequence'
    plt = ShowImageInteractive(wintitle, imgpath, imgtitle, imgpause)

    y_n= input("is this clear? >> ")    # want focus back to terminal to answer question

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also any suggestions for labeling windows and opening them are greatly appreciated but again, Linux friendly!

Comment: Don't quote me as it has been a long time since I last looked into a similar use case, but IIRC matplotlib only spawns the figure process, your window manager determines which window gets focus. At the time, I worked out a solution using `devilspie` that would detect matplotlib windows with a particular name and then handle them appropriately. `devilspie` has been discontinued, IIRC, but I am sure that there are other solutions for linux nowadays. No idea what to use on Windows.

Comment: Apparently, there is [devilspie 2](http://www.nongnu.org/devilspie2/), albeit also already in search of a new maintainer.

Comment: Final thought: If you want to interleave code, command line, and figures, why would a jupyter or google colab notebook not be a good fit for your use case?

Comment: I honestly haven't worked with it or know what it is. I have seen uses of import matplotlib.use('Agg'), but, unfortunately, that closes the figure and then refocuses to the terminal